# How to check if user input number is Integer?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an EditText in my app which allow the user to insert integer or float numbers, then the user can add that value to the database, i show the values from the database in a recyclerView and i have to check if the value added by the user is an integer or a float, if it's an integer i just have to show it without the point and if it's float i have to show it's with three decimal..

How can i archieve it?

The code from my adapter where i should format the value is the following:

```
    fun bind(articolo: Articolo?) {
        barcode.text = articolo?.barcode
        qta.text = articolo?.qta.toString() // here i should check if qta is integer and if not i have to format it with three decimal
        desc.text = if(articolo?.desc.isNullOrEmpty()) "-" else articolo?.desc
    }
```

articolo?.qta is FLOAT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float extension:

```
fun Float.formatForQta(): String {
    val floatString = this.toString()
    val decimalString: String = floatString.substring(floatString.indexOf('.') + 1, floatString.length)

    return when (decimalString.toInt() == 0) {
        true -> this.toInt().toString()
        false -> "%.3f".format(this)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
val result = yourFloat.formatForQta()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to check if number is integer or float.

```
    fun checkIfNumberIsInteger(number: String): Boolean {
    try {
        number.toInt()
        return true
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {

    }

    try {
        number.toFloat()
        return false
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {

    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To check if a variable is of a certain type you should use the function `is` in kotlin or `instanceof` in java.

```
if (obj is String) {
    print(obj.length)
}

if (obj !is String) { // same as !(obj is String)
    print("Not a String")
}
else {
    print(obj.length)
}
```

In your case:

```
qta.text = if(articolo is Int){do your code and return a String}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use kotlin function [toIntOrNull()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html) and [toFloatOrNull()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-float-or-null.html)